# Pushdown query in (Spark and) Databricks doesn't work with a "with statement"?

Tags: apache-spark, jdbc, databricks

I'm new to Azure databricks so hope my question is not too off. I'm trying to run a sql pushdown query in a Azure databricks notebook but with a "with statement" and its doesn't work. I tried pushdown queries like those but without succes :

```
sql = """
        with r as (select max(load_id) as load_id, table_name
        from LOG.TABLE_AND_FILE_ACQUISITION_MONITORING
        group by TABLE_NAME)
        (select * from r) t"""
```

```
sql = """
        (with r as (select max(load_id) as load_id, table_name
        from LOG.TABLE_AND_FILE_ACQUISITION_MONITORING
        group by TABLE_NAME)
        select * from r) t"""
```

After running this command :

```
df = spark.read.jdbc(url=jdbc_url, table=sql, properties=connection_properties)
display(df)
```

I receive this error : Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'.
Can someone know how the syntax to make it work ?
Thanks !

---

Comment: Yes i'm using Azure databricks

Answer (score 0):

This should be correct syntax:

```
sql = """
        with r as (select max(load_id) as load_id, table_name
        from LOG.TABLE_AND_FILE_ACQUISITION_MONITORING
        group by TABLE_NAME)
        select * from r"""
```

Comment: No sorry it doesn't work : 

sql = """
      2         with r as (select max(load_id) as load_id, table_name
      3         from LOG.TABLE_AND_FILE_ACQUISITION_MONITORING
      4         group by TABLE_NAME)
      5         select * from r"""
----> 6 df = spark.read.jdbc(url=jdbc_url, table=sql, properties=connection_properties)
      7 display(df)

com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'.

Comment: You have a "2" before "with" in your sql text. Actually some digits looking like line numbers.